# emacs org-mode: folder alias for links in org-files

Tags: emacs, hyperlink, org-mode

I'm using org-files in emacs for documentation. Is there a possibility to define an alias for a folder inside an org-file? Motivation: Say I have several file-links which belong to the same folder. If I move the files I have to change all this links. It would be easier to change only one folder-alias. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your init.el or .emacs file, you can define the variable `org-link-abbrev-alist` by doing the following:

```
(setq org-link-abbrev-alist
   '(("directory1"  . "c:/Path/") ;; Windows
     ("directory2"  . "~/Path/"))) ;; Linux/OSX
```

Alternatively, if you don't want these settings to apply to all your [org-mode](/questions/tagged/org-mode) files, you can just put the following in the header of the org-mode files you DO want the settings to apply to:

```
#+LINK: directory1 c:/Path/
#+LINK: directory2 ~/Path/
```

To then link to these files from within your [org-mode](/questions/tagged/org-mode) file(s), use the following:

```
[[directory1:file1.txt][file1.txt]]
```

If / when you move the directory, just change the abbreviations. Additional information in the [Org-mode Manual: Link abbreviations](http://orgmode.org/manual/Link-abbreviations.html)